# VS2017: VS displaying wrong platform for project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, project, platform

I have a solution originally built in VS2015 that I eventually moved to VS2017.

I've set the platform of my project to v141...however, the project is displayed in the solution explorer as "(Visual Studio 2015)".

[image]

At first I thought this was simply an aesthetic quirk, but now I've run into compiler errors that the developer of a 3rd party library I've implemented thinks might be due to compiling with VS2015 instead of VS2017.

How do I confirm that my project is indeed building with the correct toolset? My VC++ directories are all set to variable symbols (ex, "$(VC_SourcePath);") and I'm not sure where those are defined...I'm also not sure whether those paths are related to the incorrect platform display in the solution explorer at all.

**Edit: further details:** My project includes certain windows libs like "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib". I have copies of that library in both my vs14.0 folders and vs2017 folders on my machine...I renamed the ones in my vs14.0 folders and my project reported they could no longer be found. So my solution is definitely building with the wrong toolset, I'm just not sure how/where to modify the VC++ paths variables....

Comment: Have you changed the platform for all configurations? The easiest thing to do is to use the upgrade project menu

Comment: Yes, I've set the platform on all configurations properly...it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was importing an old 2015 property sheet in my .vcxproj file that was somehow causing MSBuild to use the wrong platform toolset. Swapping in the updated property sheet (from the developer whose SDK I'm using) into my vcxproj file results in the solution explorer displaying the correct platform and the build succeeding.